# How to filter a lookup field in a quick create form in Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

How can I filter the results of a lookup field in a quick create form in Dynamics CRM 2016?

I need to show only the associated records of another entity which is also a lookup field in my form:

[Example of requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g54ax.png)

Comment: This is NOT an exact duplicate, this question is about filtered lookups on Quick Create forms. The duplicate you refer to is a general question about filtered lookups.

Comment: Basically this isn't supported for Quick create forms or https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/213814

Comment: @Daryl where is the official source on this not being supported? Also, the answer provided does solve the question asked, whether supported or not, can't see why the need for the down vote...

Comment: I don't have anything more official than that...  I also didn't down vote anything...

Comment: @Daryl Sorry, I thought it was you, I've been trying to find something official with no luck, thanks anyways.

Answer (score -1):

I found the way to do it here:

[How to Use Dependent Lookups for Dynamics CRM 2013/2015/2016 Like a Pro](http://www.powerobjects.com/2016/03/15/how-to-use-dependent-lookups-for-dynamics-crm-201320152016/)

Basically, in the field properties (within the form), there is a setting to filter only the related records by selecting the fields that match in the entities you want to connect.